# XMPP socket connection disconnected when open library or go to background in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xmpp

I am working on IM application.  When I go to send any image from my library, my XMPP connection gets disconnected.

After that, when I go again to the chat page my message does not send to the recipient.

How can I make it connect even when my app is in a background state?

Comment: Try to Implement a Background Task Project

Comment: Can you please give me a sample? So that I can follow that.

Comment: Read this and check if you can work with that.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: look at this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537538/how-can-i-run-my-application-or-some-specific-methods-in-background-in-windows-p